My Android Studio can't start due to "java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: bind"
I just installed Android Studio and when I try to run it I get an error message like this
Internal error. Please refer to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708

java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: bind
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixDomainSockets.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixDomainSockets.bind(UnixDomainSockets.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.unixBind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:319)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:292)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel.bind(ServerSocketChannel.java:224)
    at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.DirectoryLock.tryListen(DirectoryLock.java:281)
    at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.DirectoryLock.lockOrActivate(DirectoryLock.java:147)
    at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.StartupUtil$lockSystemDirs$result$1.invokeSuspend(main.kt:528)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:103)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.11+0--11852314 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
C:\Users\ajair\Downloads\android-studio\jbr

I've looked for several ways to fix it but it's not quite right.

This question is similar to: Android studio isn't opening on Windows. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
